# Python3 winrm The syntax of this command is:\r\n\r\nNET LOCALGROUP\r\n[groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]\r\n

Tags: python, winrm

I have the below code

```
import winrm
import sys

session = winrm.Session('abcd.java.....', auth=('admin', 'annn'), transport='ntlm')

result = session.run_cmd('net localgroup administrators') # To run command in cmd
d = session.run_cmd('net localgroup administrator groupttu\\'+sys.argv[1]+'\add')
print(d.std_out)
print(d.std_err)
```

here it throw the error

```
'net localgroup administrator groupttu\\'+sys.argv[1]+' /add'
```

Actual command is

```
   net localgroup administrator groupttu\user1 \add
```

Please help But in python string I cannot format it properly(due to `groupttu\` so syntax error is getting

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `/add` (not `\add`)?

Comment: yeah modified but still the error persists

Comment: You may still be getting an error but it surely isn't the same one. Bear in mind that correcting one such error will not fix any others. Modify your program to print, not run, the generated command. Paste that at a command prompt and note the error. Fix it until it works. Then modify your program to produce the desired modified command. That way you separate Python errors from CLI syntax errors.